# Angular's change detections mechanism lets me down

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if, angular-changedetection

I am fightining for more than an hour by now with quite weird issue:

```
<mat-toolbar>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!isSignedIn; else elseTemplate">
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="signInOptions">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
      </button>
      <mat-menu #signInOptions="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <app-google-auth></app-google-auth>
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #elseTemplate>
      <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="userOptions">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        {{ signedInUser.displayName }}
      </button>
      <mat-menu #userOptions="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item (click)="signOut()">
          Sign Out <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

...and code behind the abovegiven view:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const authStateChangedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<firebase.User>(null);
    this.angularFireAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
      next => authStateChangedSubject.next(next),
      error => authStateChangedSubject.error(error),
      () => authStateChangedSubject.complete());
    authStateChangedSubject.pipe(
      tap(
        firebaseUser => {
          if (firebaseUser) {
            this.isSignedIn = true;
            this.signedInUser = firebaseUser;
          } else {
            this.isSignedIn = false;
          }
        }))
      .subscribe();
  }
```

**Use-Case #1, valid one**: user is NOT signed in; then he or she goes through the google-auth procedure (with popup mechanism provided by the Firebase) and **ng-if get's updated instantly as expected**.

**Use-Case #2, invalid one**: after user got signed in and **refreshed the page** - even though `console.log` reports that `isSignedIn` becomes `true` as expected - no visual change happens unless one hits the button; only after that button gets re-rendered to a proper `ng-if` option.

I am far from beingh Angular guru and don't know much about change detection mechanism. SOS.

Comment: is the problematic component using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` by any chance?

Comment: where are you calling that `console.log` in the 2nd case? you might want to add another `tap` after the existing one and log the state of both the flag and signed user values

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, nope, I tried both, actually, hoping to solve the problem easily. Neither way works.

Comment: Bolean flag gets updated properly. UI does not rerender unless one hits the button; then it changes instantly and display proper data without any additional work (no HTTP, no observable, nothing).

Comment: any changes in the behavior if you move the callback code from `tap` into `subscribe`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cookie/JWT to maintain your session? The refresh may be destroying your session and wiping out the isSignedIn value.

However, try using two-way binding to ensure the component and DOM stay in sync:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="[(!isSignedIn)]; else elseTemplate">
```